# How to change template based on login user in apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

We have created new end user in the Apex application.we want to hide some reports to new created users.I am able to restrict page based on acess control but i want to hide that report link in the template while this user is logged in...

Answer (score 2):

Answer depends on how you have implemented report navigation links.

If you are using Navigation Menu based on SQL query, then you can modify it to display only menu items that are applicable to a particular user type or role.

For every other implementation including bookmarks, you can add display conditions.

Follow this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/available-conditions.htm#HTMDB25942) for information on how to implement conditions.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it is to use conditions. While editing an element (a region for example), go to "Conditions", "Condition type" and click on the drop down menu there to see your options.

You should be able to access the current user by using the apex variable `:APP_USER`.